# Is it possible to prevent uniswap from listing or changing your token?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, erc-20, contract-design

we need to deploy a private business token with a fixed price for exclusive internal use (It is complicated to explain here in a few lines but it is related to workers' meals in restaurants).

We want it to only be able to be minted to new owners from our dapp and only transferred between the owners, to avoid the possibility of speculating on it by ill-intentioned people.

Is it possible to prevent uniswap (and other swaps or dex) from listing or changing the token? May be a black list of addresses stored in the smart contract? Any idea?

Thanks !

Comment: On public blockchains transactions can be sent publicly, not from specific apps, maybe you want to use some private blockchain.

Comment: We know blockchains transactions are public...  We don't want the transactions to be private. We want that it is not possible to speculate with the value of the token. The purpose of the token is not to earn money, but to transfer it (it is associated to meals not money). Unfortunately the only model of fungible tokens in Ethereum is the ERC-20. DEXs like uniswap are great for trading and economic speculation. But it also allows monopoly of a token creating a pool. How can we avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

If the token really is "only transferred between the owners", and assuming they act in the best interests of the token, then they wouldn't need to list it in the first place.

Besides that, if you can't guarantee that it won't be transferred, I see there's a couple of possibilities.

1. Have a two way exchange on your dapp that allows the token to be both bought for a certain amount of ETH, and `simultaneously the ability to be redeemed for a certain amount of ETH`. You want these values to be very close to the desired price. Essentially, your dapp is now the DEX, and this will ensure that the token will always stay close to the desired price because otherwise, there will be easy arbitrage opportunities with other DEXes. This solution doesn't involve preventing uniswap from listing the token, but it maintains the idea that the price will always stay in a certain range even if other DEXes list it. However, this will only work if the two-way transfer of assets isn't interrupted in your dapp.
2. Whitelist owners using merkle trees. Override the `transfer` function in ERC-20 to only allow only whitelisted owners to receive your token.
3. Blacklist DEXes. However, new DEXes will continue to pop up, and you'll have to blacklist them each time.
4. [Prevent contracts from owning any of your tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644395/how-to-find-out-if-an-ethereum-address-is-a-contract#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20way%20in,with%20humans%20and%20other%20contracts.). Granted, this means you'd have to whitelist the contracts used in your dapps, but otherwise it will prevent any dapp from using it (or even any external service for that matter).

Comment: Thanks. 1- the problem here is that a owner could sell coins underpriced (understand that the company gives away tokens for their meals.). 2-   is no valid cos owners can transfer by the same reason like in the 1 case. 4- In this case the token could not be used in contract wallets like Gnosis-safe.  -->  My question really is, how to avoid from the solidity contract that the token can be listed and transferred in a certanly DEX for eg Uniswap. Any hint with code for the black list option? Thanks!